# Log4j properties not working with SLF4J

Tags: java, maven, logging, log4j, slf4j

I'm trying to migrate a Java application that uses log4j 1.2.6, to use SLF4J. To start with, I'm just trying to get it to work with log4j 1.2.6 as the logging implementation. The log4j configuration is getting loaded from the database and then set using PropertyConfigurator.configure(). This has been working fine before trying to migrate to SLF4J.

However, after I converted the logging calls to use SLF4J and added the required entries in my pom.xml file, the log4j implementation doesn't appear to be impacted by the PropertyConfigurator.configure() call. The application appears to be logging using log4j, but it's just logging to the console, and not how it should based on the PropertyConfigurator.configure() call.

Interestingly, if I use a log4J logging call, those log as expected, using the confuration set via the PropertyConfigurator.configure() call.

Here is a snippet of my code;

```
import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
...
public class Initialization extends HttpServlet {
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger ( Initialization.class );  
private static final org.apache.log4j.Logger log4j = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Initialization.class);
...
PropertyConfigurator.configure ( logProps );

log4j.error("This gets logged as expected based on the log4J config set by the above call.");
log.error("This gets logged to the console.");
```

Here is what I have in my pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
<artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
<version>1.7.25</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
<artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
<version>1.7.25</version>
</dependency>
<dependency> 
<groupId>log4j</groupId>
<artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
<version>1.2.17</version> 
</dependency>
```

**For some reason the log4J configuration getting set programmatically isn't impacting the log4J implementation being used by SLF4J. Or SLF4J isn't using the log4J implementation.**

I've also tried loading the log4j properties from a file:

```
PropertyConfigurator.configure ( sc.getRealPath ( "/WEB-INF/properties/log4j.props" ) );
```

But this had the same result. I've also tried the same thing in a NEW application, and the SLF4J log statements correctly used the log4j settings and logged correctly.

Comment: I think you'd be able to find a quick solution by building a properties file or a XML file to configure your logging

Comment: does the solution with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474954/read-properties-file-using-slf4j) help your situation?

Comment: I need to configure the logging pragmatically via the PropertyConfigurator.configure() call. That's known to work with pure log4J, and is working still when I use log4j directly. So it's not the log4J configuration.

Comment: That solution is basically what I'm doing...

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue by adding the following to the weblogic.xml file:

```
<prefer-application-packages>
    <package-name>org.slf4j</package-name>
</prefer-application-packages>
```